Conditional Fatou Lemma, is there an error in the proof, and how can it be fixed?
I am looking at the conditional Fatou's lemma here:
https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Conditional_Fatou%27s_Lemma
The statement is:

The proof is this:

From what I see the last statement is wrong? Because the ordinary Fatou's lemma gives
$$\int_A \liminf\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}E[X_n|\mathcal{G}]dP \le \liminf\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int_AE[X_n|\mathcal{G}]dP ?$$
So in in face we do not have $\ge$ but $\le$ in the last step? Do you agree? If so, is there a way to fix this proof?
